# Doctrine - ManyToMany relationship with deleting

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I need to create a `ManyToMany` relationship between two entities. Next I'm trying to delete some rows but it doesn't work. No errors occurs, no db deletions - nothing - as if it has never been launched. Could you help me with this?

**Tile entity**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use AppBundle\Traits\Timestampable;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\Repository\TileRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="tile")
 *
 */
class Tile
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $type;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $start;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $end;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="tiles", cascade={"remove", "persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_tiles")
     **/
    protected $user;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->user = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set type
     *
     * @param string $type
     *
     * @return Tile
     */
    public function setType($type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get type
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Tile
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set start
     *
     * @param string $start
     *
     * @return Tile
     */
    public function setStart($start)
    {
        $this->start = $start;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get start
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStart()
    {
        return $this->start;
    }

    /**
     * Set end
     *
     * @param string $end
     *
     * @return Tile
     */
    public function setEnd($end)
    {
        $this->end = $end;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get end
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEnd()
    {
        return $this->end;
    }

    /**
     * Add user
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\User $user
     *
     * @return Tile
     */
    public function addUser(\AppBundle\Entity\User $user)
    {
        $this->user[] = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove user
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\User $user
     */
    public function removeUser(\AppBundle\Entity\User $user)
    {
        $this->user->removeElement($user);
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }
}
```

**User entity**

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Group")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="fos_user_user_group",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    protected $groups;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Tile", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $tiles;


    /**
     * Add tile
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Tile $tile
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function addTile(\AppBundle\Entity\Tile $tile)
    {
        $this->tiles[] = $tile;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove tile
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Tile $tile
     */
    public function removeTile(\AppBundle\Entity\Tile $tile)
    {
        $tile->setUser(null);
        $this->tiles->removeElement($tile);
    }

    /**
     * Get tiles
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getTiles()
    {
        return $this->tiles;
    }
}
```

and part of controller class

```
 $user = $this->getUser();

    foreach($user->getTiles() as $tile) {
        echo $tile->getName();
        $user->removeTile($tile);
    }
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();
```

Also I'm trying to add new records with:

```
foreach($data as $tile) {
    $user->addTile($em->getReference('AppBundle:Tile', $tile));
}
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

But this also won't work. No errors occured, no database insertions.

Comment: So what exactly is happening?  Are the relations being deleted but the tiles themselves staying in the database?  It's possible that you may need orphan removal: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#orphan-removal

Comment: What doesn't work? Please be more specific.

Comment: @k0pernikus Nothing's happens. If I run code from controller rows are still in database.

Comment: @breq Are you persisting the owning side? See: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your User seems to be the inverse side and your Tiles the owning side. Hence updates to the inverse side will not reflect on your updates. Try switching the owning side or update the tiles on update.

See the [doctrine docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html):

> The inverse side has to use the mappedBy attribute of the OneToOne,
>   OneToMany, or ManyToMany mapping declaration. The mappedBy attribute
>   contains the name of the association-field on the owning side. The
>   owning side has to use the inversedBy attribute of the OneToOne,
>   ManyToOne, or ManyToMany mapping declaration. The inversedBy attribute
>   contains the name of the association-field on the inverse-side.

and

> Doctrine will only check the owning side of an association for changes.
>
> To fully understand this, remember how bidirectional associations are
>   maintained in the object world. There are 2 references on each side of
>   the association and these 2 references both represent the same
>   association but can change independently of one another. Of course, in
>   a correct application the semantics of the bidirectional association
>   are properly maintained by the application developer (that’s his
>   responsibility). Doctrine needs to know which of these two in-memory
>   references is the one that should be persisted and which not. This is
>   what the owning/inverse concept is mainly used for.
>
> Changes made only to the inverse side of an association are ignored.
>   Make sure to update both sides of a bidirectional association (or at
>   least the owning side, from Doctrine’s point of view)
>
> The owning side of a bidirectional association is the side Doctrine
>   “looks at” when determining the state of the association, and
>   consequently whether there is anything to do to update the association
>   in the database.
>
> “Owning side” and “inverse side” are technical concepts of the ORM
>   technology, not concepts of your domain model. What you consider as
>   the owning side in your domain model can be different from what the
>   owning side is for Doctrine. These are unrelated.

Comment: Thanks. I need to change a little my entity to use it both side. Here is example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33430139/1251563

Answer (score 0):

As [@k0pernikus said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33416307/1251563), it is possible only from one side. So if you want to use it both side it is required to modify the inverse entity.

So change from:

```
/**
 * Add tile
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Tile $tile
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function addTile(\AppBundle\Entity\Tile $tile)
{
    $this->tiles[] = $tile;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove tile
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Tile $tile
 */
public function removeTile(\AppBundle\Entity\Tile $tile)
{
    $this->tiles->removeElement($tile);
}
```

to

```
    /**
     * Add tile
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Tile $tile
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function addTile(\AppBundle\Entity\Tile $tile)
    {
        $tile->addUser($this);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove tile
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Tile $tile
     */
    public function removeTile(\AppBundle\Entity\Tile $tile)
    {
        $this->tiles->removeElement($tile);
        $tile->removeUser($this);
    }
```